# SQL Join two table with complex condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, query-optimization

I am trying to merge data from two tables. Following is the structure:

**Users**

```
userID (Primary Key),
firstName,
lastName.
```

Sample data:

```
[1, John, Smith]
[2, Steve, Lan]
[3, Matt, Smith]
```

**Message**

```
messageID (Primary Key),
sender_userID,
receiver_userID,
messageBody.
```

Sample data:

```
[1, 1, 1, Hello]
[2, 1, 2, Second Message]
[3, 2, 1, ThirdMessage]
[4, 2, 1, FourthMessage]
[5, 3, 3, LastMessage]
```

Now, I need to display all messages posted/received by a user ID and his colleagues.

In above sample data, userID 1 is a colleague of userID 2. So, if I query for userID = 1, then I should get message ID 1, 2, 3 [Since Message.sender_userID IN (1,2)] and 4 [Since Message.receiver_userID= 1]. MessageID = 5 should not appear because 3 is not a colleague of any one. Along with this, it should print firstName and lastName for both sender_userID,
receiver_userID.

**Result with unique messageID should be:**

```
Message.messageID, 
Users.userID (Sender), 
Users.firstName (Sender), 
Users.lastName (Sender), 
Users.userID (Receiver), 
Users.firstName (Receiver), 
Users.lastName (Receiver), 
Message.messageBody
```

I know the query can done using JOIN, but I am new to SQL and some how not able to get the desired output.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How do you know who is whose colleague?

Comment: I will be passing a set of userID who are colleagues of a userID.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/sql-difference-between-inner-and-outer-join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you define colleagues with a list. Below (1, 2) - is a list of colleagues.

```
select 
    mes.MessageId, 
    usr1.sender_userID SenderUserId, 
    usr1.firstName SenderFirstName, 
    usr1.lastName SenderLastName, 
    usr2.userID ReceiverUserId, 
    usr2.firstName ReceiverFirstName, 
    usr2.lastName ReceiverLastName, 
    mes.messageBody
from Message mes
    join Users usr1 on
        mes.sender_userID = usr1.userId
    join Users usr2 on
        mes.receiver_userID = usr2.userId
where 
    mes.sender_userID in (1,2) or 
    mes.receiver_userID in (1,2)
```

[EDIT] If you need to show only those messages that were sent or received by user 1 to/from his  colleagues, then condition would be:

```
where 
    mes.sender_userID = 1 and mes.receiver_userID in (1,2) or 
    mes.receiver_userID = 1 and mes.sender_userID in (1,2)
```

`1` - is user of interest
`(1, 2)` - is the colleagues list. (User 1 is a colleague to himself :))

Comment: Thanks Alex. I tried with mes.receiver_userID = 1 but it returns records only when receiver_userID is an colleague. I would also like to get the records where sender_ID = 1 and receiver_ID is an colleague or not.

Comment: @johnk1 - not sure I understand. This one condition `mes.sender_userID in (1,2) or mes.receiver_userID in (1,2)` will show both whenever 1 is sender or receiver. If this is not what you want, you might need to refine your question with a better example.

Comment: Let me take my example again:
[messageID=1, sender_userID=1, receiver_userID=1, messageBody=Hello]
[2, 1, 2, Second Message]
[3, 2, 1, ThirdMessage]
[4, 2, receiver_userID=1, FourthMessage]
[5, 3, 3, LastMessage] 
[6, 1, 7, LastMessage] 
[7, 2, 9, LastMessage] 
[8, 1, 9, LastMessage] 

So, in above case, for userID = 1 and his colleague set as (1,2), the query should return me messageID 1,2,3,4,6,7,8. Note that in messageID 7,8, receiverID = 9 which is not in colleague set. receiverID will always be equal to 1.

I hope this doesn't confuse more.

Comment: @johnk1 - I'm sorry. I don't understand. My first query will return 1,2,3,4,6,7,8 for this example, won't it?

Comment: @Alex You are right. The first query does the magic. It was problem with my data. There were no records in user table for userID=3,7,9. So no messageID record with those userID was getting pulled. Thanks. Don't know when I would start writing quick and instant queries like you :) .

Comment: @Alex One more thing: 
I have added a new field which will indicate whether the message is private or public. 
Private = 1 and public = 0.

Modified your suggested query:

where 
    mes.sender_userID = 1 and mes.receiver_userID in (1,2) or 
    mes.receiver_userID = 1 and mes.sender_userID in (1,2)
    AND mes.message_visibility = 1

I created only one private record and executed above query. Instead of the getting only one record, I am getting more than one. Geting wrong records in case of message_visibility = 0 too. How do I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand, although trying hard. I suggest creating a new question showing sample input and expected output. I or somebody else will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean "where sender or receiver = 1" to define "colleagues" based on your logic. If colleague is defined elsewhere we'd need more info.

```
SELECT 
   M.messageID,
   USend.firstName AS firstNameFrom,
   USend.lastName AS lastNameFrom,
   URrec.userID,
   URrec.firstName AS firstNameTo,
   URrec.lastName AS lastNameTo,
   M.messageBody
FROM
   Message M
   JOIN
   User URrec ON M.receiver_userID = URrec.userID
   JOIN
   User USend ON M.sender_userID = USend.userID
WHERE
   M.receiver_userID = 1 OR M.sender_userID = 1
```